# How to broadcast two access points?

Tags: dhcp, hostapd, udhcpc

How do I broadcast two access points with two WiFi cards with hostapd? Most tutorials don't work since udhcpd doesn't work with two access points.

Example tutorial: http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux. Perhaps you could add links to these tutorials? These would be helpful to anyone that might attempt to answer your Q.

Answer (score 0):

Supply 2 config files on the command line, e.g. hostapd /etc/hostapd/a.conf /etc/hostapd/b.conf. I don't understand how udhcpd gets into the picture. I simply used the same dhcpd that serves all other interfaces.

Comment: I just tried that, and that worked perfectly to broadcast two access points, but I'm not getting DHCP on the access points. How do you have dhcpd configured to run DHCP on the access point?

Comment: Run 2 instances of udhcpd ?

Comment: subnet 192.168.131.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  authoritative;
  deny unknown-clients;
  # range of dynamically allocated IPs.
  range 192.168.131.128 192.168.131.240;
}
subnet 192.168.132.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  authoritative;
  option routers elanor-gray;
  option domain-name-servers elanor-gray;
  option domain-name "zaitcev.lan";  ((ugh stackexchange comments not the best forum for this...))